# How to check product is already added using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I decide to develop shopping cart application using ASP.NET MVC and Knockout. As starting point, I'm following [Knockout Cart Editor Example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html).

At the example, I can select category for example: 'Classic Cars' and the product is '1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster', then I clicked Add product to add new product. I can select the same category and same product, which is already added before.

What I want is if I've added product 1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster (Classic Cars), I cannot add a new one with the same product and category?

Answer (score 1):

Well you will have to redo this entire thing and make it work like this:
Clicking the add button will add the newly created line to the array.
In this example clicking that button just adds an empty one, so checking it for doubles is impossible.
If you however catch the filled in object when clicking the add button, you can check it against the array that you are filling.

Comment: No problem! Hope you figure it out. It is a good exercise to get to know ko.